# Which one is the best database design for supporting multi-currency money values?

Tags: database, database-design, currency

I want to know the best database design for storing multi-currency money values in database.
For example I have one Entity that has two money fields. These fields may have different currency types for each record.

Example:

```
Table A:
-------------
Id
Name
Amount1
Amount2
```

Sample records:

```
Id  Name    Amount1 Amount2
1   aaa     12$     15£
2   bbb     30€     17$
```

I cannot store values in one currency. For example I want to lend somebody money. I store its data in a table. The type of money can be different. When I lend someone 10€ I should take back 10€ and I cannot store all values in one currency like dollar.

I want to know what the best and more efficient design for storing these values in database is.
Should I store amount and currency sign in one column with string data type or it is better to define `Money` and `Currency` tables as separate tables for storing money values?
Or any other design?

Comment: Never ever store multiple values in the same column!! 

The currecny and the amount need to be separated. Also, if you have column names with numbers then you most probably do something wrong.

Comment: And why do you need to store multiple amounts? Can't you just calculate the amounts on the actual currency exchange rates?

Comment: I almost hit close - opinion based :) Well, we are using few amount fields (for document and accounting and some other currency), then some currency rate fields, then N1 link to currencies table, which holds some properties of currency and which is 1N linked to daily currency rates table, which is nightly updated with european central bank data and helps to enter documents in different currencies :)

Comment: @juergend Rates change, payments and currency conversion documents can have different rates, conversion with rate is not precise etc etc.

Comment: How do you decide which currencies, out of the thousands available, you use? I understand why you might need to record an immediate spot rate currency, but if there is a variable number of them then they belong in a separate table with currency and amount columns. Its a 1:N relationship.

Comment: @juergend For example I want to lend somebody money. I store its data in a table. The type of money can be different. When I lend someone 10€ I should take back 10€ and I cannot store all values in one currency.

Comment: Your example about lending and receiving money consists probably from more than one record, both records can be linked to different currencies. If you plan to include many money transactions withing single record (document) then you need separate 1N linked table for monetary amounts and currencies. In our system (what I described above) we never need more than three amounts/currencies for same record (document/transaction amount and amounts in primary and secondary accounting currencies) and therefore we have triplicate amount fields - to make queries faster.

Answer (score 7):

Without commenting too much on the actual structure of your table (2 or more monies in a single table is OK, as long as they have business meaning—like `subtotal`, `shippingFee` and `total`), I'll focus on *how* to store them:

### Storing the monies

You should store the amount in one column, and the currency code in another.

#### Currency

You'll typically deal with [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217), which comes with 2 codes for each currency:

- a 3-letter alpha code, such as `EUR` or `USD`
- a 3-digit numeric code, such as `978` or `840`

Which one you use is up to you. You can save one byte per record by using numeric codes. On the other hand, alpha codes are easier to read and remember for humans, and could make it easier to use custom currencies (crypto), that may have a de-facto standard alpha code but no numeric code.

#### Amount

Because currencies may have different numbers of decimal places (2 for `EUR`, `USD` etc., but 0 for `JPY`, 3 for `TND`...), I always advise to store amounts in *minor currency units* (cents) as an integer.

Your table would therefore look like:

```
amount INT NOT NULL,
currencyCode CHAR(3) NOT NULL
```

If you want to store `12.34 USD`, you'll actually store `(1234, 'USD')`.

#### Multiple amounts, single currency

If your table holds several monies that will always be in a single currency (like the `subtotal`/`shippingFee`/`total` example above), all 3 amounts can share a single currency code:

```
subtotal INT NOT NULL,
shippingFee INT NOT NULL,
total INT NOT NULL,
currencyCode CHAR(3) NOT NULL
```

In this case, you probably don't need separate `subtotalCurrencyCode`, `shippingFeeCurrencyCode` and `totalCurrencyCode`, although there are other business cases where amounts *will* be in different currencies. The decision is yours.

### Retrieving the monies

Of course dealing with integer amounts is not very easy, so you'll need to use a money library that supports converting from/to minor amounts.

For example in PHP, you can use [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) (disclaimer: I'm the author):

```php
$money = Money::ofMinor(1234, 'USD');

$money->getAmount(); // 12.34
$money->getMinorAmount(); // 1234
```

Comment: very comprehensive answer

Answer (score 0):

### Never ever store multiple values in the same column!!

The currecny and the amount need to be separated. Also, if you have column names with numbers then you most probably do something wrong. This is one way to do it:

```
table products
--------------
id
name


table prices
------------
id
product_id
amount
currency_id


table currencies
----------------
id
name
abbreviation_sign
```

Then to get the Dollar price of a product you can do

```
select pri.amount 
from prices pri
join products prod on prod.id = pri.product_id
join currencies c on c.id = pri.currency_id
where prod.id = 123
and c.name = 'Dollar'
```

With proper indexes this is really fast to query.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have two column for each money value in all tables even with more than one money value in each table?

Comment: You should design your tables in a way that they don't have to change if you data changes. What if you need another currency? Then add two more columns to the tables? Better not.